# What does 'export default {}' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, export

I have seen in a file that many things have been done but at the end it reads

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-ajax-click]', function(e) {

  ...

  let prmData={};

  ...

}

export default {}
```

What does this do? Exporting an empty object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems like the author of that file wants to export an empty object.

Maybe it's just a placeholder and in the next future it will be a filled object exported.